# Filter related models by Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two models in my aplication, Delivery and DeliveryProblem.
DeliveryProblem has a PK (delivery_id) from Delivery:

```
static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Delivery, {
      foreignKey: 'delivery_id',
      as: 'delivery',
    });
  }
```

I need select all Deliveries that have a Delivery Problem.
In my Controller, a have the follow method:

```
async index(req, res) {
    const response = await DeliveryProblem.findAll({
      order: ['id'],
      attributes: ['delivery_id'],
    });

    // Filter all Deliveries with problem
    const ids = [...new Set(response.map((x) => x.delivery_id))];

    const deliveries = Delivery.findAll({
      where: , // <<< How can I filter ?
      order: ['id'],
    });

    return res.json(deliveries);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Op = Sequelize.Op
...
// Filter all Deliveries with problem
const ids = [...new Set(response.map((x) => x.delivery_id))];
const deliveries = Delivery.findAll({
  where: {
   id: {
     [Op.in]: ids
   }
  },
  order: ['id'],
});
```